# PHP dynamically reference variable in string literal

Tags: php, dynamic, string-literals

I have multiple PHP variables in the form

```
$number1, $number2, $number3 and so on...
```

I would like to dynamically reference these inside of a loop to retrieve information from them, but am not sure how to reference the static variable dynamically. Ex:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    //The first number to be printed should be the value from
    //$number1 not $number concatenated to $i

    //here are some of the strings I tried:
    echo "$number$i";
    echo "{$number}$i";
    echo "{$number}{$i}";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
echo ${"number{$i}"};
```

But why not use arrays instead? Having `$number[$i]` is much more readable...

Comment: Thanks, thats worked! And I would use arrays, but I am only supposed to change a function that manipulates variables already there.